# finding limit of a sequence of vectors

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, analysis, convergence-divergence

Can someone help me with this limit problem:

> Using the definition of a limit in one and multiple dimensions, prove that if $\vec{a}_n \in \mathbb{R}^d$ is a sequence of vectors and $\vec{a} \in \mathbb{R}^d$ is a vector, then $\vec{a}_n \to \vec{a}$ if and only if $\left(\vec{a}_n\right)_i \to a_i$ for all $i=1, \ldots, d$, where $\left(\vec{a}_n\right)_i$ is the $i^{\mathrm{th}}$ coordinate of $\vec{a}_n$ and $\vec{a}_i$ is the $i^{\mathrm{th}}$ coordinate of $\vec{a}$.

Comment: what are your thoughts?

Comment: $||a_n - a||^2 = (a_n[i] - a_[i])^2$ for all $i = 1,...,d$

Comment: Then I thought I could maybe do something with that

Answer (score 2):

**HINTS**

You need to prove 2 things.

1. If limit exists in each dimension, it also exists in $\mathbb{R}^n$. This can be shown directly -- if in each dimension, the error is small enough, you can bound the norm of the entire error vector.
2. If the limit exists in $\mathbb{R}^n$, it also must exist in each dimension. Here, I would go by contradiction, so assume limit in $\mathbb{R}^n$ exists but in some (WLOG the first) coordinate it does not converge to the needed value. Then, show the error cannot be bounded as the $n$-dimensional definition requires, achieving a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I don't understand it completely though. What do you mean by "Error vector"?

Answer (score 2):

In general, suppose that $(X,d_X)$ and $(Y,d_Y)$ are two metric spaces. The question is if we can define a metric $d_{X\times Y}$ on $X \times Y$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(x_n,y_n)=(\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n,\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n)$. So, the idea of passing the limit inside the ordered pair is the essence of defining a metric on the Cartesian product space.

It turns out that we can achieve this in several ways. The most famous product metrics are the ones defined using the $\mathcal{L}^p$ norm in the following way:

$$d_{X\times Y}((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))=\sqrt[p]{d_X(x_1,x_2)^p+d_Y(y_1,y_2)^p}$$

In particular, your case is when $p=2$. Namely, the Euclidean metric. I'm going to show you why this definition works the way we wanted it to work only for the case when $p=2$, but you can do the same for other $1 \leq p < \infty$ nearly the same way. It doesn't hurt to know that when $p=\infty$, the $\mathcal{L}^p$ norm becomes the maximum norm. But it's not necessary to know this now.

Assuming that $x_n \to x$ and $y_n \to y$, it's easy to see that we have:

$$d((x_n,y_n),(x,y)) = \sqrt{d_X(x_1,x)^2+d_Y(y_1,y)^2} \leq d_X(x_n,x)+d_Y(y_n,y) \to 0$$

Hence, $(x_n,y_n) \to (x,y)$.

Conversely, if $(x_n,y_n) \to (x,y)$, it's easy to see that:
$$d_X(x_n,x) \leq \sqrt{d_X(x_1,x)^2+d_Y(y_1,y)^2}=d((x_n,y_n),(x,y)) \to 0$$
$$d_Y(y_n,y) \leq \sqrt{d_X(x_1,x)^2+d_Y(y_1,y)^2}=d((x_n,y_n),(x,y)) \to 0$$

Hence, both $x_n \to x$ and $y_n \to y$ are true.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have just started the course though, and I have never heard about metric spaces :s

Comment: @tonytouch  You're welcome. Ignore the parts I wrote about metric spaces. You can come back to this answer in future when you have studied them. But even if you know nothing about metric spaces, the rest of the proof about why $(x_n,y_n) \to (x,y) \iff x_n \to x \text{ and } y_n \to y$ should be accessible to you. It uses nothing but a minimum knowledge of high school algebra and inequalities. Let me know if you have any questions concerning the proof.